# Problem with Term Store

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I have received the below email from my client:

> I am trying to block certain terms in the Term Store from being used
>   for tagging.
>
> In this site
>   https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-manage-terms-in-a-term-set-549070a7-41c2-4210-9e9c-5fad22bd8748
>   it states that when I ‘Deprecate a term’, that term itself cannot be
>   used for tagging, but its child terms are not affected and can still
>   be used for tagging.
>
> Hoever, when I do this in the Term store, the child terms will also be
>   affected and are also blocked (I tried to deprecate ‘Agencies’ and its
>   child terms like ‘CAD’ and ‘SPF’ are also deprecated)

Why this is happening? Is our interpretation of what stated in Microsoft site is correct? if not, what is it stating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That article is inaccurate. If you deprecate a term it and all child terms are hidden.  If you don't want people to use a term but you want child terms to be available un-check available for tagging:

[image]

[edit] To check this out in more detail I accessed a term set in CSOM. I can access any terms under the deprecated term and they are not flagged as deprecated. So in theory the article is correct but in practise the GUI will hide the term and any children.

Comment: Can you please suggest any official link to substantiate that the article in MS site is not correct, so that i can explain this to my client. He is referring the link and demanding a justification.

Comment: I think the fact it doesn't work as advertised substantiates it. I removed the link because I clearly can't read...

Comment: It Worked !. Client was convinced. Thank you so much.